# Show values from datagridView in combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have  for example this values in datagridView : 1;2;3;4;

I want display this values in combobox like this :
 1 
                                                   2 
                                                   3 
                                                   4 
My code show only last value in combobox: 4 
My code of showing :

```
        string cmbValue = CmbText;
        string[] cmb = cmbValue.Split(new[] { ';' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        for (int i = 0; i < cmb.Length; i++)
        {
            comboBox1.Text = cmb[i];

        }
```

and here is my code of creating array of combobox and calling method to change cell in dataGrid:

```
            string cmbText = comboBox1.Text;
            string[] cmb = new string[] { cmbText};

            frm1.ChangeCellCmb(2, cmb);
            this.Dispose();
```

Someone know how to do this ? I cant simply set collection of values combobox, because values of combobox are reading from datagrid and it's reading from DB.
Many thanks.

Comment: `comboBox1.Items = cmb`

Comment: Well you can assign a `DataSource` to your combobox or just add the required ones to the `Items` collection like `combobox1.Items.Add(your value)`

Comment: yes i just add  combobox1.Items.Add(your value); and works perfect thanks V4V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop and add the required items as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cmb.Length; i++)
    comboBox1.Items.Add(cmb[i]);
```

This will add all the required items to the drop down menu. To select/display '4' the 3rd entry in `cmb` by default do

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 3;
```

or

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem = "4";
```

I hope this helps.